# How to fix Google Webmaster XML Sitemap error

Tags: html, xml, sitemap, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I am getting error on Google search console for XML Sitemap.

**Sitemap.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/channels/</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
</urlset>
```

> **Error**: Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare the
> namespace.

[image]

**Sitemap Index XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://example.com/sitemap_main.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

> **Error** : Your Sitemap or Sitemap index file doesn't properly declare
> the namespace.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct URL, as I checked your sitemap on online tools, it does not cause any issue, and passing all checks.

Comment: Cross posted: [How to fix an XML sitemap that Google says doesn't properly declare the namespace?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/141731/how-to-fix-an-xml-sitemap-that-google-says-doesnt-properly-declare-the-namespac)